# Glyph 144 missing from current font

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts

I'm on a mac using **matplotlib.pyplot**

I have been searching for a while to solve the problems.

I have try:

```
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm, rcParams

plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']=['SimHei'] #Show Chinese label
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus']=False
```

BUT, it DOESN'T work.

I find the number after "Glyph" in the solution above is much larger than mine. I suppose the solution can only solve warnings such as: Glyph 39057, Glyph 24352 ...

My warning is:

```
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:238: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 150 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=flags)
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:201: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 157 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:201: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 132 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:201: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 144 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:201: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 156 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:201: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 151 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:201: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 152 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:201: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 128 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:201: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 153 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
```

New to Python and ipynb, Thanks for the help!